# Load iframe's popup in the same iframe

Tags: javascript, ipad, web-applications, iframe, popup

I'm writing a web app for tablets, which will connect to my client's project management scheduler software. Their software has a web interface, which I want to put in an `iframe`.

However, when navigating to the web interface, it wants to start a session and open a popup. I want that to be invisible to the users, meaning I want the `iframe` to open the popup into itself essentially. If it opens, the device switches to a browser, taking them out of the app.

Comment: If you don't have access to their code there's not much you can do about their popup